# wxAssertFailure for progress dialog bar over a period of time

Tags: memory-management, progress-bar, wxwidgets

I am using the wxProgressdialog to show time between switching ports and time between taking measurements.  I am running this test for over 24 hours (repeating the same thing over and over while recording the data).  Therro that appears during hour 7 is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\Thermal\Cheyenne_Antenna_Cal_PDA_Thermal_Test.py", line 2117, in take_measurements_at_interval
    self.take_measurement(self)
  File "C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\Thermal\Cheyenne_Antenna_Cal_PDA_Thermal_Test.py", line 2185, in take_measurement
    self.Measure_Plot(self)
  File "C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\Thermal\Cheyenne_Antenna_Cal_PDA_Thermal_Test.py", line 2231, in Measure_Plot
    style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_windows.py", line 2951, in **init**
    *windows*.ProgressDialog_swiginit(self,*windows*.new_ProgressDialog(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed at ....\src\msw\control.cpp(159) in wxControl::MSWCreateControl(): CreateWindowEx("STATIC", flags=52000100, ex=00000000) failed

Here is the code that is being used to 'delay time'

```
#Giving Time for switch to toggle next port
        progressMax = 5
        dialog = wx.ProgressDialog("A progress box", "Time to switch", progressMax,
                                   style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME)
        keepGoing = True
        count = 0
        while keepGoing and count < progressMax:
            count = count + 1
            wx.Sleep(1)
            keepGoing = dialog.Update(count)

        dialog.Destroy()
```

The code pauses 5 seconds to allow switch hardware and PNA to be steady before data is recorded.  All of this is happening in a 'For' loop for a period of time.  If anyone needs more information I will be happy to proved.

Comment: Which platform/toolkit/OS version? What wx version? Can you reproduce it in C++ sample?

Comment: This is in Python 2.7, Windows 7, and I will try to reproduce this in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If the window creation fails after running for a long time, chances are you simply run out of windows, which are still a very limited resource under Microsoft Windows (the exact limit depends on the Windows version, but could be as log as 16,384).

This could happen if you never return to the main event loop during all this time because the top level windows will only be really destroyed (and not just hidden) once you get back to it.

Comment: OK, rather than use a 'for' loop, I am looking into ' itertools.repeat(object[, times]) ' but the thing that I am reading is that it does not calculate until the end of the 'times' duration.  Is that correct??

Comment: Sorry, please reformulate this, I don't understand what are you saying.